# htaccess redirect in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

By using WordPress with Divi and custom php pages/scripts I ended with urls looking like this:

```
https://example.com/?day=today
https://example.com/?sport=1&league=123 (1=football and 123=premier_league)
```

I want to make them more user and SEO friendly and rewrite them in htaccess to:

```
https://example.com/?day=today ==> https://example.com/today
https://example.com/?sport=1&league=123 ==> https://example.com/football/premier_league
```

For the "day" link I tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /?day=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

For the other example with sport and league I wanted to find a solution in which I will manually add old link and new link, tried redirect 301, but I think it can't work, right?

```
Redirect 301 https://example.com/?sport=1&league=123 https://example.com/football/premier_league
```

I also tried Redirection plugin in WP, but it created Rule which destroys page and makes error 500:

```
RewriteRule ?sport=1&liga=123 https://example.com/football/premier_league [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sport=1&league=123$
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/football/premier_league [R=301,L]
```

which gaved address: https://example.com/premier_league/?sport=1&league=123

I was also wondering if I can make it with pure php, since in PHP I can easilly get proper strings for id's of the sports and leagues. Unfortunantelly changing "?sport=1&league=32758" into "?sport=football&league=premier_league" and then clean it with rewrite in htacces is not possible right now.

I'm not expecting whole code for both problems, I believe that some directions would be enough. I browse stack and google and coudn't find any examples with links that looks like mine, so example.com/?sport=1 not example.com/page?sport=1

After further investigation I believe the problem is in the way I'm opening my custom pages. I'm using shortcodes to initiate a script and inside the script my php code is included with parameters. I think that because of that I got to this page https://example.com/premier_league/?sport=1&league=123 which was pretty close, but not working.
Now my question is how to send those parameters to proper script but not into url.

Comment: Isn't this done by turning on Permalinks inside the WordPress admin and using the default htaccess?

Comment: I don't know if I understand You correctly, but those php pages are our custom  pages, not included in WordPress itself. We are using shortcodes inside functions.php in WP to open them properly.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: With the last attempt your have shown, add a question mark at the end of the target URL - that will prevent the original query string from being taken over.

Comment: That "?" at the end is creating proper url, but my PHP code is not working. I presume that the problem is with shorcodes that I'm using to include my script.